# Why does the Stopwatch value change by an order of 10 with a Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, stopwatch

I'm seeing this very strange behavior with the `Stopwatch` object that I can't explain, in my code. I wrote this very simple application to reproduce the behavior and it's still there. In a brief summary, if I add a `Thread.Sleep(1)` in the loop, but **outside** of the timing portion, it changes the loop's time by an order of 10.

Here is the complete code.

```
public static void DoStuff()
{
    long ticks;
    double seconds;

    ticks = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

    if (ticks % 2 == 0)
    {
        ticks = ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    }
    else
    {
        seconds = ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int loopCount = 1000;
    List<double> times;

    Console.WriteLine("Loops = " + loopCount);

    // No sleep
    times = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        DoStuff();
        sw.Stop();

        times.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

        // Thread.Sleep(0);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("--- No sleep ---");
    Console.WriteLine("Average = " + times.Average() + " s");
    Console.WriteLine("Average = " + (times.Average() * 1000000000).ToString("N2") + " ns");

    // Sleep
    times = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        DoStuff();
        sw.Stop();

        times.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("--- Sleep ---");
    Console.WriteLine("Average = " + times.Average() + " s");
    Console.WriteLine("Average = " + (times.Average() * 1000000000).ToString("N2") + " ns");

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here are the results of running that piece of code, and it is consistent. I can run this a few tens of times and if I have a `Sleep(1)` in there then the stopwatch timing changes completely. I don't know which number to believe. <s>I do understand that `Sleep(0)` doesn't actually put the thread to sleep, just requeues it. However, the same behavior happens if I do a `Sleep(0)` or if I just comment out that line of code.</s>

[image: Results]

I have tried only instatiating the `Stopwatch` object just once and calling `Restart()`, `Reset()`, and `Start()`, but that didn't make a difference either. I don't know if this is more of a threading question or `Stopwatch` issue.

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: I tried your code, the elapsed time is similar https://dotnetfiddle.net/RNP9Jz

Comment: Did you test this in release mode? Have you tried a slow DoStuff? Since your current method actually did nothing, it might be optimized.

Comment: Yeah, in the project where I noticed this, I was running the test in release mode without debugging and the "DoStuff()" function did contain useful/executable code.

Comment: Hard to explain.  It doesn't have anything to do with .NET, exact same machine code, no  garbage collection, repro with different frameworks.  The difference is larger than presented here, Average() is not a good way to profile code due to outliers produced by jitting and pinvoke stub generation overhead.  A wild guess is power management, where Sleep(1) convinces the OS that the processor doesn't have to be cranked up.  Win10 version 2004 had very large changes in the Sleep() plumbing btw.

Answer (score 4):

As you mention `Sleep(0)` will just allow the scheduler to run something else, in most cases you will have cores available, and the program will just continue to run.

`Sleep(1)` on the other hand will actually suspend the thread, likely for a full 16ms, and the CPU will just be idle if there is nothing else to run. But you are not measuring the sleep, only the time of `DoStuff()`, so why does it matter?

A likely explanation is caches. If your thread gets suspended for what amounts to an eternity in CPU time, it is very likely that any data in the CPU caches will get discarded and replaced. So when the thread eventually get to run again it has to fetch things from main memory, since a main memory access takes on the order of 100ns, a few cache misses could easily explain the difference in time.

Another possible explanation is frequencies and power. If the CPU is idle it will reduce frequency and power, as it starts working it will take some time to ramp up again. The details are rather complicated, and will vary between processors.

But in any case it is likely that you are measuring differences in actual CPU time. You might be able to use [intel VTune](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/vtune-profiler/cookbook/2023-0/instruction-cache-misses.html) if you really want to dig into the details of what the CPU is doing.

Comment: This was one of my thoughts too, but my computer isn't very busy and pretty powerful in the RAM/CPU department. I've also tried setting this process to real-time priority and fixing the affinity, thinking that it could be a processor/cache issue, but it still exhibits the same behavior. I can't imagine that in 1ms that many cache misses would happen, but you could be right, very possible.

Comment: @Maty as Matthew Watson mentions, the actual sleep time should be 15.6ms. But even 1ms is a long time for a CPU,  If the cpu is doing anything else at all it will likely quickly fill the caches with other data, some of it may even be caused by the task switching itself. I think Intel have some low level profiling tools if you want to investigate the actual details.

Comment: @Maty And if the CPU *is* completely idle you might just be observing the CPUs ramp up behavior as it increase in frequency and/or low power states.

Answer (score -1):

The [default timer resolution on Windows](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/socwatch/user-guide/2020/timer-resolution.html#:%7E:text=The%20default%20timer%20resolution%20on,interrupt%2064%20times%20a%20second.) is 15.6 ms, so all your sleeps are by default going to be approximately a multiple of 15.6 ms.

It's possible to increase the resolution of the timer by calling [the Windows API `timeBeginPeriod()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod)

You would need to call `timeendperiod()` to return to the normal resolution.

You can call these from C# using the following P/Invokes:

```
[DefaultDllImportSearchPaths(DllImportSearchPath.System32)]
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint="timeBeginPeriod", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern uint TimeBeginPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

[DefaultDllImportSearchPaths(DllImportSearchPath.System32)]
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint="timeEndPeriod", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern uint TimeEndPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);
```

***NOTE***: It's not really advisable to mess around with this, because it's a system-wide setting, so changing it will affect all apps. I'm just posting this information so you can play around with it if you want to experiment.

On Windows, the `Stopwatch` class is implemented using the Windows API [`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter) which is not affected by the current windows timer resolution, and hence is a lot more accurate and precise.

Comment: So if any timing number, including ticks, that is below 15.6 ms then I can't trust it?

Comment: @Maty Stopwatch usually have very good precision and resolution, See the [Stopwatch.Frequency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency?view=net-7.0) to for more information. The 15.6ms applies to the resolution of `Thread.Sleep`, and most other timers.

Comment: Yes like Jonas said: `Stopwatch` resolution is very good, but `Thread.Sleep()` (and other things such as `DateTime.Now`) have poor resolution.

Comment: Ah, thanks. My Stopwatch.Frequency is 10,000,000, based on that, I should be somewhat accurate to the 100 ns?

Comment: Yes, sounds right.